# How to find a set of elements of a specific size that include the greatest possible sets in a collection of sets?

Tags: algorithm, set, mathematical-optimization

Given a family of finite sets with cardinalities between 1 and 6, which themselves are subsets of a larger finite set of possible elements, my goal is to create sets of elements that are the most inclusive, ie, the elements of the created sets can be used to create the most possible sets from within the family of sets. I'm not entirely sure if I stated that problem correctly, as it has been a long time since I studied these types of problems in school, but let me try to clarify through an example.

Here is an example of the family of sets with the maximum number of elements being 6:

```
{1029}
{1029}
{1049}
{1029,1049}
{1029,1049,1118,1125}
{1029,1112,1125,1505}
{1029,1049,1094,1112,1505,1525}
{1029,1125,1138,1505,1525}
{1049,1094,1125,1182,1525,1531}
```

These sets are created from a larger finite set of elements:

```
{1029,1049,1094,1112,1118,1125,1138,1182,1505,1525,1531}
```

The goal is to create sets of no more than 6 elements that can be used to recreate the maximum number of sets in the family. Here is an example an answer set:

```
Created Set 1: {1029,1049,1112,1118,1125,1505}
```

That created set's elements could be used to re-create 6 of the sets in the family.

```
{1029}
{1029}
{1049}
{1029,1049}
{1029,1049,1118,1125}
{1029,1112,1125,1505}
```

Hopefully that makes sense. Obviously the family of sets is much larger as is the Set of possible elements. I would also need to repeat this process of creating sets until all sets in the family could be re-created.

I'm really looking for an algorithmic solution, written in any programming language or pseudocode would be especially helpful, but even a mathematical formula that I can use to translate into code is helpful. I'd even be happy if I could figure out what the name of this type of problem would be so I could do more effective research into it myself. Thank you!

Comment: Suppose you had created sets A and B, Are you allowed to create a set by chosing some elements from A, and some from B? For example if 1 was in A, but not B, and 2 wasin B but not A, and if one of your original sets was {1,2}, would you say that could be created?

Comment: Thank you for your response @dmuir. Yes, you can choose any elements from any set within the collection. The goal is to just maximize the created sets coverage. Upon further research, I'm thinking this might be a variation of the Set Cover Problem, but most of the resources I'm trying to digest are scholarly articles and a little over my head to be honest. Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As I see it this is straightforward. As a matter of terminology I'll call your given sets the original ones, and the sets you manufacture the chosen ones. The key difference between this and the set cover problem is that you don't need the chosen sets to be taken from the original ones.

An original set can be 'created' from a chosen set if and only if the original set is a subset of the chosen one. Similarly an original set can be created from a collection of chosen sets iff it is a subset of the union of the chosen sets. So all the original sets can be created iff the union of the original sets is a subset of the union of the chosen sets. So you can manufacture the chosen sets by taking the union of the original sets and then dividing that union -- in any way you please -- into a collection of sets of no more than 6 elements.

Comment: Thank you again @dmuir, I was basically following that same path, but I don't know if I'm doing it in an optimal way. I will share my code or pseudocode with you later this afternoon and hopefully, if you have a moment to review, you could provide any insight or responses!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured out an answer, although it may not be the most optimized solution ever. If anyone can help me get this running faster, or perhaps help me write this in such a way that it is able to find the optimal top 3, I would appreciate it. Here's my code, note that I am using the data structure "Set", available from https://github.com/php-ds

```
class ProductionOptimizer{
    private int $CARDINALITY=6;
    private CombinationsIterator $combinationsIterator;
    private array $tickets;
    private Set $threads;

    public function __construct(array $array){
        $this->tickets=$array;
        $start = microtime(TRUE);
        $this->threads=new Set();
        foreach ($array as $ticketThreads){
            foreach ($ticketThreads as $thread)
                $this->threads->add($thread);
        }
        $end = microtime(TRUE);
        // print_r($this->threads);
        echo PHP_EOL."Creating the Set took " . ($end - $start) . " seconds to complete.";
        $this->combinationsIterator=new CombinationsIterator($this->getThreadsAsArray(),6);
    }

    public function outputThreads() : void {
        print_r($this->threads);
    }

    public function getThreadsAsArray() : array {
        return $this->threads->toArray();
    }

    public function getCombinationsIterator() : CombinationsIterator{
        return $this->combinationsIterator;
    }

    public function createNewCombinationsIterator(array $array, int $subsetCardinality=null) : CombinationsIterator {
        if(is_null($subsetCardinality)) $subsetCardinality=$this->CARDINALITY;
        $this->combinationsIterator=new CombinationsIterator($array, $subsetCardinality);
        return $this->combinationsIterator;
    }

    public function removeFromSet(array $array){
        // var_dump($this->threads);
        echo "Removing Threads(before count :".$this->threads->count().")...".PHP_EOL;
        $this->threads->remove(...$array);
        // var_dump($this->threads);
        echo "Removing Threads(after count: ".$this->threads->count().")...".PHP_EOL;
        $this->combinationsIterator=new CombinationsIterator($this->getThreadsAsArray(),6);
    }

    public function getSet() : Set {
        return $this->threads;
    }
    public function getThreads() : Set {
        return $this->threads;
    }

    /* not need if using Set class */
    /*
        Set:
            The code took 4.5061111450195E-5 seconds to complete.
        This Function:
            The code took 0.0054061412811279 seconds to complete.
    */
    public function deduplicateArray($array){
        array_walk_recursive($array, function($v) use (&$r){$r[]=$v;});
        return array_values(array_unique($r));
    }

}

class CombinationsIterator implements Iterator
{
    protected $c = null;
    protected $s = null;
    protected $n = 0;
    protected $k = 0;
    protected $pos = 0;

    function __construct($s, $k) {
        if(is_array($s)) {
            $this->s = array_values($s);
            $this->n = count($this->s);
        } else {
            $this->s = (string) $s;
            $this->n = strlen($this->s);
        }
        $this->k = $k;
        $this->rewind();
    }
    function key() {
        return $this->pos;
    }
    function current() {
        $r = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < $this->k; $i++)
            $r[] = $this->s[$this->c[$i]];
        return is_array($this->s) ? $r : implode('', $r);
    }
    function next() {
        if($this->_next())
            $this->pos++;
        else
            $this->pos = -1;
    }
    function rewind() {
        $this->c = range(0, $this->k);
        $this->pos = 0;
    }
    function valid() {
        return $this->pos >= 0;
    }

    protected function _next() {
        $i = $this->k - 1;
        while ($i >= 0 && $this->c[$i] == $this->n - $this->k + $i)
            $i--;
        if($i < 0)
            return false;
        $this->c[$i]++;
        while($i++ < $this->k - 1)
            $this->c[$i] = $this->c[$i - 1] + 1;
        return true;
    }

}
```

and here is some sample data to test. this will get the top 3 ordered sequences, removing the matching sets from the the universe of sets with each iteration:

```
function humanReadableMemory($size)
{
    $unit=array('b','kb','mb','gb','tb','pb');
    return @round($size/pow(1024,($i=floor(log($size,1024)))),2).' '.$unit[$i];
}
$tickets = [
    [1029],
    [1029],
    [1029],
    [1029],
    [1029],
    [1029],
    [1029],
    [1029, 1049],
    [1029, 1049],
    [1029, 1049, 1080, 1112, 1125, 1188],
    [1029, 1049, 1125],
    [1029, 1049, 1188, 1278],
    [1029, 1056, 1138, 1158, 1182, 1514, 1531],
    [1029, 1071, 1076],
    [1029, 1074, 1075, 1092, 1093, 1242, 1523, 1525],
    [1029, 1094, 1125, 1138, 1158],
    [1029, 1094, 1125, 1278],
    [1029, 1094, 1182, 1221, 1242, 1505],
    [1029, 1094, 1278, 1298],
    [1029, 1094, 1298],
    [1029, 1112, 1125, 1298, 1516],
    [1029, 1112, 1125, 1505],
    [1029, 1112, 1505],
    [1029, 1125],
    [1029, 1125],
    [1029, 1125, 1138],
    [1029, 1138, 1188, 1514, 1517],
    [1029, 1138, 1242, 1317, 1505, 1525],
    [1029, 1242],
    [1029, 1242],
    [1029, 1242, 1270, 1524],
    [1029, 1242, 1370, 1505],
    [1029, 1298],
    [1029, 1298, 1505],
    [1029, 1317],
    [1029, 1505],
    [1029, 1505],
    [1029, 1505, 1525],
    [1038, 1076, 1177, 1182],
    [1045, 1048, 1097, 1100],
    [1046, 1125, 1182, 1242, 1278],
    [1049],
    [1049],
    [1049],
    [1049],
    [1049],
    [1049],
    [1049],
    [1049],
    [1049]
];
$po=new ProductionOptimizer($tickets);
$start = microtime(TRUE);
$end = microtime(TRUE);
echo "Current Memory Usage: ".humanReadableMemory(memory_get_usage()).PHP_EOL;
echo "Peak Memory Usage: ".humanReadableMemory(memory_get_peak_usage()).PHP_EOL;
echo "Starting Iterations and Combination Testing...".PHP_EOL;
$rankedOutput=[];
$start = microtime(TRUE);
for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
    $matchCountArray=[];$bestChoice=0;$bestChoiceId=-1;
    foreach ($po->getCombinationsIterator() as $comboTest){
        $combinationString=implode(",",$comboTest);
        $matchCountArray[$combinationString]=0;
        $comboTestSet=new Set($comboTest);
        foreach ($tickets as $ticketIdx=>$ticketElements) {
            $ticketElementsSet = new Set($ticketElements);
            $testsArray[$combinationString]+=($comboTestSet->contains(...$ticketElements) ? 1 : 0);
        }
        if ($matchCountArray[$combinationString]>$bestChoice) {
            $bestChoice = $matchCountArray[$combinationString];
            $bestChoiceId=$combinationString;
        } else {
            //trying to save memory
            unset($matchCountArray[$combinationString]);
        }
    }
    $currentBestChoiceSet=new Set(explode(",",$bestChoiceId));
    $currentUniverseSet=$po->getSet()->copy();
    for($tmpJ=0;$tmpJ<$currentUniverseSet->count();$tmpJ++){
        $testAgainstSet=$currentUniverseSet->get($tmpJ);
        if ($currentBestChoiceSet->contains(...$testAgainstSet->toArray())){
            $currentUniverseSet->remove($testAgainstSet);
        }
    }
    $tickets = [];
    foreach ($currentUniverseSet as $singleSet){
        $tickets[]=$singleSet->toArray();
    }
    $po=new ProductionOptimizer($tickets);
    $rankedOutput[$i]=["greatest_matching_sequence"=>$bestChoiceId, "coverage_count"=>$bestChoice];
}
echo "RankedOutput:".PHP_EOL;
var_dump($rankedOutput);
echo PHP_EOL;
$end = microtime(TRUE);
echo PHP_EOL."The code took " . ($end - $start) . " seconds to complete.".PHP_EOL;
```